# WebViewer o QWebBrowser para QT4

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qt-designer

Actualmente estoy usando QtextBrowser para que me muestre el texto de una url en una ventana. El problema es que con QTextBrowser no cargo las imagenes de la url, solo el texto.

He observado que en QT5 se usa QwebBrowser, pero el problema surge porque todo esta compilado en QT4.

Hay alguna metodo para poder mostrar las imagenes de una url? puedo importar el metodo QwebBrowser de QT5 en Qt4?

Gracias

Comment: Échale un vistazo al siguiente [ejemplo](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-activeqt-webbrowser-example.html) hecho en Qt4

Comment: En Qt5 no existe QwebBrowser, quizas te refieras a QWenEngineView, que en el caso de Qt4 podrias usar QWebView. Aunque te recomendaria migrar a Qt5 ya Qt4 hace años es deprecated.